# Mapping object with properties names and values

Tags: c#

I have class

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

I want to convert the object to a generic object

```
{
    "properties": {
        "id" : "1234",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email" : "john.doe@mail.com"
    }
}
```

I want to convert the class instance to the structure where the properties would be dynamic depending on the class. Is this possible with Automapper?

Comment: There might, Reflection going to help you with your work. Please be more specific what you exactly want to map.

Comment: Why not using Newtonsoft?

Comment: Is your format supposed to be Json? If so, have you looked at any C# Json frameworks (like the above mentioned Newtonsoft.Json)?

Comment: @vesan : yes my final output will be eventually json for consumption

Answer (score 4):

Seems you want to serialize/deserialize to/from JSON. In this case you can reference to [**Newtonsoft.Json**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`/`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` generic method which does not depend on any specific class:

**Deserializing (From String to Class Instance):**

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString);
```

**Serializing (From Class Instance to String):**

```
var stringValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)
```

**One More Point (Mapping)**

Also you may want to decorate your class with some attributes to specify the mapping:

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string Email {get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: And also JSON and class properties must be matched and they are case sensitive.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid There is no obligation for the matching. I edit my post.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid thanks for your effort in order to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Partially</del> AutoMapper cannot map to dictionary or ExpandoObject, so no.

The following solution was posted before I was aware that by mapping to an ExpandoObject Automapper will simply leave you with an empty object.

The simplest solution would be this I think (assuming you want an ExpandoObject as a result):

```
public ExpandoObject Map<TInput>(TInput inputObject)
{
  dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
  result.properties = Mapper.DynamicMap<TInput, ExpandoObject>(inputObject);
  return (ExpandoObject)result;
}
```

<del>As far as I know you can't delegate all members as child properties to another field using automapper, but it's simple to do this yourself.</del> AutoMapper is completely useless here.

edit: seems that automapper struggles with ExpandoObject... Actually it seems like AutoMapper cannot do this at all, so you're left with reflection.

You would then write a reflection object that can create or populate a dictionary with the objects properties.